# how to prevent user from copying text

Tags: html, css

is there a way to prevent user to copy text but keeping the text cursor?

i know we can use `user-select:none` like this

```css
p{
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
```

but it changes the cursor to default

Comment: pointer-events: none;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a extra CSS property [`cursor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor) to set the cursor.

```css
p{
  user-select: none;
  cursor: text;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
```

Comment: omg how can i not realize this xD, thanks